# How to fix 'dependencies manifest not found' error when running Add-Migration in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net

Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64', version: '6.0.16'
path: 'System.Private.CoreLib.dll'

I get this error when running Add-Migration

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.